# Регулярное выражение в C++

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка типа:
Abcd 17:25 18:01
и регулярное выражение, которое не распознается. Помогите найти ошибку, пожалуйста

```
[Abcd\w]+\s\d{0,24}\:\d{0,24}\s\d{0,24}\:\d{0,24}
```

Answer (score 0):

нашел ошибку. в С++ нужно ставить двойной слэш

```
[Abcd]+\\s\\d{0,24}\\:\\d{0,24}\\s\\d{0,24}\\:\\d{0,24}
```

Answer (score 0):

`\d{0,24}` совпадает, например, со строкой `123456789012345678901234`, вы точно это имели в виду?  Двоеточие экранировать не надо.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/220834)

Comment: @DeKaNszn В вопросе просили указать на ошибки в составлении выражения. Указываю на одну ошибку и одну неточность.